# Type SocketFactory is deprecated

Tags: java, android, httpclient

My application goes to Performance review stage. So Performs team told me there are some deprecated methods are available, write latest versons.

My part of the code is :

```
  private void workAroundReverseDnsBugInHoneycombAndEarlier(HttpClient client) {
    // Android had a bug where HTTPS made reverse DNS lookups (fixed in Ice Cream Sandwich) 
    // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13117
    SocketFactory socketFactory = new LayeredSocketFactory() {
        SSLSocketFactory delegate = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        @Override 
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return delegate.createSocket();
        }
        @Override 
        public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params) throws IOException {
            return delegate.connectSocket(sock, host, port, localAddress, localPort, params);
        }
        @Override 
        public boolean isSecure(Socket sock) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            return delegate.isSecure(sock);
        }
        @Override 
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
            injectHostname(socket, host);
            return delegate.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        }
        private void injectHostname(Socket socket, String host) {
            try {
                Field field = InetAddress.class.getDeclaredField("hostName");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(socket.getInetAddress(), host);
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    };
    client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
}
```

Here `SocketFactory ,LayeredSocketFactory,SSLSocketFactory,HttpProtocolParams ...` says

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The method getParams() from the type HttpClient is deprecated
- The method setUserAgent(HttpParams, String) from the type HttpProtocolParams is 
 deprecated
- The type HttpProtocolParams is deprecated
- The method getParams() from the type HttpClient is deprecated
- The method setContentCharset(HttpParams, String) from the type HttpProtocolParams is 
 deprecated
- The type HttpProtocolParams is deprecated
```

another sample `deprecated`

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type SocketFactory is deprecated
- The type LayeredSocketFactory is deprecated
- The type SSLSocketFactory is deprecated
- The type SSLSocketFactory is deprecated
- The method getSocketFactory() from the type SSLSocketFactory is 
 deprecated
- The type SSLSocketFactory is deprecated
```

Please guide me . I am using HttpClient 4.3.jar file.

Please tell me any ideas...

Comment: There might not be another workaround for the bug. Maybe you need to discuss this with your performance team as a special case.

Comment: Any person or system that tells you that SSLSocketFactory is deprecated is dreaming and should be ignored or questioned closely or re-educated, forcibly if necessary.

Comment: Application indicated as deprecated. `eclipse ide`  `Sonar` and `finshEye` also indicate deprecated

Comment: Deprecated by whom? They're not so marked or annotated in the Javadoc.

Comment: javadoc say its Deprecated

Comment: The current [Javadoc of SSLSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) says no such thing. If you're talking about something outside the JDK you should specify what exactly it is. People will assume you're talking about JDK classes unless you specify otherwise. Any *documented* deprecation usually tells you what to use instead. Have you looked?

Answer (score 1):

**The method getParams() from the type HttpClient is deprecated**

Before 4.3.2 you could set the parameters to the client using the `getParams()` method (deprecated now), after 4.3.2 you can set the request params via the `RequestConfig` class using a `Builder`

```
Builder requestConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
requestConfigBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000).setMaxRedirects(1);
```

and then set to the HttpMethod only (not to client like before)

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(builder.build());
request.setConfig(requestConfigBuilder.build());
```

**The method setUserAgent(HttpParams, String) from the type HttpProtocolParams is deprecated**

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setUserAgent("Agent").build();
```

**The method setContentCharset(HttpParams, String) from the type HttpProtocolParams is deprecated**

Use [AbstractHttpEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/AbstractHttpEntity.html) subclasses (BasicHttpEntity, ByteArrayEntity, EntityTemplate, FileEntity, InputStreamEntity, SerializableEntity, StringEntity)

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://");
post.setEntity(new StringEntity("content", "UTF-8"));
```

**The type HttpProtocolParams is deprecated**

(4.3) use configuration classes provided '`org.apache.http.config`' and '`org.apache.http.client.config`'

```
Builder requestConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
```

**The type SocketFactory is deprecated & The type LayeredSocketFactory is deprecated**

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();

// Allow TLSv1 protocol only
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
        sslcontext,
        new String[] { "TLSv1" },
        null,
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

or

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .useTLS()
        .loadTrustMaterial(myTrustStore)
        .build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
```

then

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

You can take a look at [HttpClient Tutorial (4.3.x)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/index.html) for more examples and explanations

I hope this helps you.